# Are Answers in the Form "Solution X also works for me on platform Y" Helpful?"

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a question by saying that a previously posted solution  that worked for another user on his system also worked for me on a different system.  A user with far more reputation than I commented that I should simply have upvoted the previous answer, rather than posting another answer.  I searched SE and Google for advice or rules on whether answers for SE in the form "solution x also works for me on platform y" are considered helpful, but didn't find any. I find such answers help me and think they might help others, but am glad to be corrected if necessary. Is there some guidance or rationale on this that I have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that answers saying only that thing, (that thing means previously posted solution work him on Y too), then it didn't worth an answer instead it should be either **a Comment or an Edit** to the Answer saying *this works on Y too*

Flag it as VLQ and then for LQP reviewers, there is an option this should be a comment and recommend deletion